# proper way to store large numbers in a variable

Tags: java, math, types

I would like to play around with numbers and however elementary, Ive been writing algorithms for the fibonacci sequence and a brute force path for finding prime numbers!

Im not a programmer, just a math guy.

However, a problem I run into quiet often is that a long long, double and floats often run out of room.

If I wanted to continue to work in JAVA, in what way can I create my own data type so that I dont run out of room.

Conceptually, I thought to put 3 doubles together like so,

```
public class run {

    static double a = 0;
    static double b = 0;
    //static double c = 0;

    static void bignumber(boolean x) {

        if (x == true && a < 999999999) {
            ++a;

        } else if (x == true && a == 999999999) {
            ++b;
            a = 0;
        }
        System.out.print(b + "." + a + " \n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
        bignumber(true);

        }
    }

}
```

is there a better way to do this,

I would like to one day be able to say

mydataType X = 18476997032117414743068356202001644030185493386634
10171471785774910651696711161249859337684305435744
58561606154457179405222971773252466096064694607124
96237204420222697567566873784275623895087646784409
33285157496578843415088475528298186726451339863364
93190808467199043187438128336350279547028265329780
29349161558118810498449083195450098483937752272570
52578591944993870073695755688436933812779613089230
39256969525326162082367649031603655137144791393234
7169566988069

or any other number found on [this site](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2093)

I have also tried

```
package main;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class run {
    BigDecimal a = 184769970321174147430683562020019566988069;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

But it still seems to be out of range

Comment: Take a look at `BigInteger`

Comment: Never create your own; you are unlikely to get higher performance than something someone else built already.

Comment: C my edit, that solves you edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BigDecimal` (instead of `double`), and `BigInteger` (instead of `int`, `long`) for that purpose, But you can only work with them by their methods. No operators, can be used.

Used like this:

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("4019832895734985478385764387592") // Strings...
big.add(new BigInteger("452872468924972568924762458767527");
```

Same with `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal is the class used in java where you need to represent very large or very small numbers, and maintain precision. The drawbacks are that it is not a primitive, so you can't use the normal math operators (+/-/*/etc), and that it can be a little processor/memory intensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can store large numbers like this:

- length
- digits[]

and implement your math for them. This is not very complicated. As a hint, to make everything more simple you can store the digits in reverse order. This will make your math simpler to implement - you always add nr[k] with nr[k] and have room for transport for any length numbers, just remember to fill with 0 the shorter one.

In Knuth Seminumeric Algorithms book you can find a very nice implementation for all operations.